# Can't edit the padding for mat-radio-button in angular-material v15

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to edit the padding to 0 such that the radio button and the label appears closer. I am able to do this in the browser by editing mdc-radio class and setting the padding to 0px. However, this class appears to be auto-generated. Below is my code for mat-radio button

```
     <mat-radio-group  [(ngModel)]="options">

      <mat-radio-button class='radio-button' value="%">%</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button class='radio-button' value="#">#</mat-radio-button>

    </mat-radio-group>
```

I tried every combination of ng-deep, !important, but unable to select the .mdc-radio class in css.

Below is the browser html. Using angular v15, material v15.

```
<mat-radio-button _ngcontent-ffb-c47="" value="%" class="mat-mdc-radio-button radio-button" ng-reflect-value="%"><div class="mdc-form-field"><div class="mdc-radio"><div class="mat-mdc-radio-touch-target"></div><input type="radio" class="mdc-radio__native-control"><div class="mdc-radio__background"><div class="mdc-radio__outer-circle"></div><div class="mdc-radio__inner-circle"></div></div><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-mdc-focus-indicator"><div class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></div></div></div><label>%</label></div></mat-radio-button><mat-radio-button _ngcontent-ffb-c47="" value="#" class="mat-mdc-radio-button radio-button" ng-reflect-value="#"><div class="mdc-form-field"><div class="mdc-radio"><div class="mat-mdc-radio-touch-target"></div><input type="radio" class="mdc-radio__native-control"><div class="mdc-radio__background"><div class="mdc-radio__outer-circle"></div><div class="mdc-radio__inner-circle"></div></div><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-radio-ripple mat-mdc-focus-indicator"><div class="mat-ripple-element mat-radio-persistent-ripple"></div></div></div><label>#</label></div></mat-radio-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok was able to figure it out, it seems that ::ng-deep will not work, but !important is needed. If anyone can explain why this works, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
.mdc-radio {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```